# Projector black at any resolution when connecting MacBook Pro Retina

Tags: macbook-pro, display, projector

A colleague of mine bought a brand new MacBook Pro Retina. She wants to use it in lectures in connection with a projector. I can't tell what brand the projector is of since it is a very big lecture hall. But it is definetly a good and expensive one. So I don't think the following problem occurs on that end of the connection:

Whenever she connects her MBP to the projector with a HDMI cable, the MBP seems to detect it and changes its resolution. But the display on the wall stays black no matter which resolution I choose in the system preferences.

Has anybody experienced something similar? Could it be a problem with the color profiles?

Answer (score 1):

Opposite of your thoughts that the problem lies at the Mac end, I'd personally search on the projector first.  If the supplied signal is somehow out of range, the projector should beam some feedback by showing an error on the wall.

Perhaps you haven't selected the right source on the projector.  Does the projector handles a different HDMI source correctly?

Being such an expensive projector and all, connecting it to a (n old) Apple TV could do wonders.  It's cheap, neat, wireless and well implemented in OSX and iOS.  If your environment is Apple focused I won't hesitate and try it out.

Comment: I can't access the projector. And actually they are twin projectors. I only have acess to a very neat console where I have a tablet to choose the signals I want each projector to use. I definetly have not used the wrong signals. I also tried different HDMI channels in order to be sure that the problem lies not there.

Comment: I don't know your projector, but ours surely do like to complain. If the signal is out of range, complains.  If the signal cable is disconnecte, complains.  If the signal stream is empty, complains.  If yours doesn't, it might either be because your projector thinks there's nothing to complain about, or complains are turned off.  What happens if you disconnect the HDMI cable out of your Mac?

Comment: Then the resolution on the MBP display changes and the projector goes into its blue screen again...